# pub get failed:version solving failed

Tags: flutter

Flutter_test depends on meta 1.1.8 and firebase_login depends on meta ^1.2.2.
firebase_login depends on flutter_test any from sdk, version solving failed.
pub get failed

pubspec.yaml

```
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  firebase_auth: ^0.18.0+1
  equatable: ^1.2.4
  google_sign_in: ^4.5.3
  meta: ^1.2.2

  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.3

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  lint: any
```

Comment: Checkout : https://pratikbutani.medium.com/flutter-2-upgrade-flutter-version-solving-failed-error-33ac1087cb6b

Answer (score 7):

You can get both by

```
dependencies:
  meta: ^1.2.2

dependency_overrides:
  meta: ^1.1.8
```

Answer (score 2):

I have same problem with bloc:

*Because every version of passcode_navigator from git depends on flutter_bloc ^7.3.3 and every version of feature_menu from path depends on flutter_bloc ^8.0.0, passcode_navigator from git is incompatible with feature_menu from path*

I resolve it with adding to pubspec:

```
dependency_overrides:
  flutter_bloc: any
```

Comment: The `any` thing solved my problem. Appreciate a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Do this,

```
meta: ^1.1.8
```

And then, run this,

```
flutter pub get
```

Comment: Please upvote and accept this as the answer if it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

hi there try to downgrade the version of meta to 1.1.8 i tried and it worked with me in flutter 1.20.1

Answer (score 0):

I experienced a similar issue with Firebase auth and permission_handler:

```
# pubspec.yaml: 
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  firebase_auth: ^1.4.1
  permission_handler: ^5.1.0+2
```

The error message (truncated):

```
Because permission_handler ^5.1.0 depends on permission_handler_platform_interface ^2.0.2 which depends on plugin_platform_interface ^1.0.2, permission_handler ^5.1.0 requires plugin_platform_interface ^1.0.2.
And because firebase_auth 1.4.1 depends on firebase_core_platform_interface ^4.0.1 and no versions of firebase_auth match >1.4.1 <2.0.0, permission_handler ^5.1.0 is incompatible with firebase_auth ^1.4.1.
So, because my_flutter_project depends on both firebase_auth ^1.4.1 and permission_handler ^5.1.0+2, version solving failed.
```

A solution that worked for me:
Update permission_handler to the [latest version](https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler/install):

`flutter pub add permission_handler`

Answer (score -1):

Update meta to 1.2.2

```
meta: ^1.2.2
```

also update flutter using flutter upgrade command

```
flutter upgrade
```

Comment: Sorry actually it was 1.2.2 i typed it wrong in question

Comment: what is flutter_test